# Items are missing on Order Details Page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, database, composer, magento2.4.0

I am getting an error, when customers are placing an order then on In admin Sales=> Order details page Orders items are missing. But invoice is created successfully. All items are coming in when I am printing the invoice of Pdf but not showing on the order details page. I don't know why this error is coming. Anyone can help me regarding this issue. I am using Magento 2.4.0. Please check the attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: did you check var/log for any error ?

Comment: there is not showing anything in log

Comment: Check the console log, is there anything there? And also to disable third party extension one by one and check.

Comment: actually this issue is coming randomly, i have face this issue in 3 orders rest 97 orders are showing fine. That's why i am confused about this issue.